# How to Update Android Client's Database With Server Efficiently

Tags: java, android, http

I have written an android application that does a lot of data trading with the server. Smallest row in my server database, after appending, is 100 string chars. I will have at least 1 million rows that all need to be updated on client side. What I have done is making a column called "version" on server side and client side. So, when a version number has changed, it means the row data has changed and needs to be updated. When the version is 0, the row is deleted and out of use. What I do is sending the versions available in my client side to the server with a "," between them, then I split at server side like this:

```
3,21,1,5,1,0,1
```

My server which is a java sun's http, will know that the first number (3) is for the first row of both databases sides,  and will then compare and send necessary information back. But still, 1 million of 100x strings is a lot for the first time they trade.

Now I'm wondering if I am doing the right way and/or if there is any better way or library so I can achieve what I need , or if there is any way to reduce size of data sent by encoding etc. I am using printwriter on the server side for writing strings, and okhttp's Source.body().inputStream() for reading strings on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to implement [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). In such architecture your server will only tell to all of your clients that there is new data available. In receiver that receive the message you will download new bunch of data.

Comment: That is not possible in my case, that is for chat like app, s .

Comment: It is nonsense. It is well fitted for your app. You only download the data when you need it. I am not talking that you should send data through GCM. You should send only an info that data update is available. Gmail works that way with millions of users and emails and everything is fine.

Comment: Yes but that gonna need some sort of login , and gms is for real time apps, in my case there is  no login, just like taking image from sitee

Comment: I thing you don't get the point of how this is working. You do not need any logo